# Decimal GCC library

Tags: c++, gcc, decimal

I wrote this simple code just to check whether the `#include <decimal/decimal>` worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <decimal/decimal>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o exe
```

But I get this error message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/decimal/decimal:39:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for ISO/IEC TR 24733 that is currently not available.
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/decimal/decimal:230:56: error: unable to emulate 'SD'
/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/decimal/decimal:251:5: error: 'std::decimal::decimal32::decimal32(std::decimal::decimal32::__decfloat32)' cannot be overloaded
```

... lots more similar errors ... (removed by Mats Petersson)

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message directly.

Comment: Put the error message inline - don't make us click a link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really couldn't indent it, it would take me weeks to do that...

Comment: `#error This file requires compiler and library support for ISO/IEC TR 24733 that is currently not available.`
What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Strange, your code compiles in my 4.6.3.

Comment: With `sudo port select --list gcc` it says `Available versions for gcc:
 llvm-gcc42
 mp-gcc47 (active)
 none`

Comment: Don't trust port. What is the result of `g++ --version`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth how did you indent the code so quickly?

Comment: Did you by any chance build your own libraries? `#ifndef _GLIBCXX_USE_DECIMAL_FLOAT` is what decides if you can do this or not. Which appears to be a setting when compiling the compiler and/or the libraries - I haven'd dug any deeper.

Comment: @fpiro07: Select it in the editor, and then click the **{ }** button.

Comment: What do you mean by "build your own libraries"? I actually tried a few times to build GCC by myself before using MacPorts...

Comment: @pmr also with `g++ --version` it says it's 4.7.2

Comment: Ah, on a Mac, I didn't notice that you were using Mac. In which case, it may be that the compiler built for Mac doesn't support this option? I don't know, I don't have a mac to test on.

Comment: Is there a way maybe to uninstall GCC with all the parts I installed in the other tries and then reinstall it from scratch?

Comment: FWIW I can reproduce this problem with GCC 4.7.2 on OS X installed via Homebrew (which, incidentally, is vastly superior to Macports).

Comment: Ok so maybe that's a bug in GCC 4.7.2. Maybe with GCC 4.6 it will work, could it?

Comment: Could anyone explain what <decimal/decimal> is supposed to include, and where I can find the documentation? I understand it's TR 24733 for decimal numbers but would like to learn more.

Comment: @JohanLundberg <decimal/decimal> is the header for the decimal floating point types which accord to the ISO/IEC TR 24733 standard. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr24733) the documentation

Comment: And, btw, it didn't worked even with GCC 4.6, I've just tried

Comment: @fpiro07 According to the TR, shouldn’t the header actually be `<decimal>`? (Not that it works …)

Comment: Actually I don't know but the file `decimal.h` is located at: `/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/decimal`, not at: `/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++` so it's reasonable to `#include <decimal/decimal>`

Comment: @MatsPetersson what are you running GCC on? Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm on a Linux machine with the gcc supplied by Fedora.

Comment: I think I'm gonna try to install a virtual machine with Linux and compile the file on that machine...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Will Ubuntu 12.10 work?

Comment: Can't say, as I've not got Ubuntu on my home machine. I can try Ubuntu 12.04 on Monday when I'm at work.

Answer (score 4):

When building gcc you can enable support for C's decimal support of [TR24732](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1312.pdf). The C TR creates built-in types like `_Decimal64`which are given nicer names by including `<decimal.h>`, e.g., `decimal64`. These built-in types are also available in C++ when gcc is configured when building to include decimal support.

The decimal support forC++ is defined by [TR27433](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) and would be made available by including `<decimal/decimal>`. With gcc decimal support in C++ seems to be only available if gcc is compiled with decimal support enabled, i.e., it seems it uses the same built-in types as the C code does.

In either case it seems the decimal support in gcc doesn't cover everything specified by the respective TRs. In particular, last time I checked I/O support was missing.

Comment: So is there a way to make it work? How can I build GCC with decimal support enabled?

Comment: @fpiro07: When configuring gcc you need to add `--enable-decimal-float` to enable decimal support. With this configuration it *used* to work for me but currently I can only compile but not link the code (I tried with the current SVN head of gcc on MacOS). It doesn't find certain symbols dealing with the basic operations when linking and I failed to locate them in the installed libraries (... and they also don't seem to be present in the built object files).

Comment: Do you also know how to enable the decimal support with MacPorts?

Comment: @fpiro07: I have no idea of MacPorts. I got XCode, installed the shell utilities, and keep building gcc and clang directly. I have found what is needed to enable linking: in `<trunk>/libgcc/Makefile.in` it seems to be necessary to add a line `DFP_ENABLE = 1`. Without this, a couple of necessary objects files aren't built.